# iphone sdk - XML parseErrorOccurred: how to get rid of the illegal charaters when parsing in XML?

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing

When pasrsing XML using NSXMLParser, I encountered this problem when the parser received some characters that it couldn't take such as: the auto-correct "..." or "--" in MSWord.

My app reads XML which is exported out of my database from a PHP file. I wonder if I should handle this on the server side or on the iPhone SDK and How?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like an encoding issue.

Are you sure that the XML file is being served as the same encoding as in its header?

Comment: I should handle this on the server side then.